# An inequality involving $\frac{x^3+y^3+z^3}{(x+y+z)(x^2+y^2+z^2)}$

Tags: inequality

> $$\frac{x^3+y^3+z^3}{(x+y+z)(x^2+y^2+z^2)}$$
>
> Let $(x, y, z)$ be non-negative real numbers such that $x^2+y^2+z^2=2(xy+yz+zx)$.
>
> **Question:** Find the maximum value of the expression above.

My attempt:
Since $(x,y,z)$ can be non-negative, we can take $x=0$, then equation becomes

$$y^2 + z^2=2xy$$

This implies that $(y-z)^2=0$.
So this implies that the required value is $$\frac{y^3 + z^3}{(y+z)(y^2 + z^2)}=\frac{1}{2}$$

But this wrong as the correct answer is $\frac{11}{18}$.

What is wrong with my method?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. This question is missing context or other details: Please improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it. This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level.

Comment: Could you tell what made you take $x=0$?

Comment: @Dhruv Since I wasn't able to make head and tail out of this question, I decided to plug in some boundary values.

Comment: There is no reason to believe $x=0$ when the maximum is achieved.  In fact all you have done is prove when one of the variables is zero, the maximum is $\frac12$, you have not said anything about what could happen when all variables are strictly positive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose one of the variables is zero.  Then you have shown the maximum is $\frac12$.

So let us consider the case when none of the variables are zero.  Then as both the objective and constraint are symmetric & homogeneous, we may set WLOG $z=1$ and $1\ge x\ge y>0$.  Thus in this case we have the constraint $x^2+y^2+1 = 2(x+y+xy) \iff (x-y)^2+1=2(x+y)$ and need to maximize
$$F=\frac{x^3+y^3+1}{(x+y+1)(x^2+y^2+1)} $$
Now let $u= x+y, v = x-y \implies v^2+1=2u$.  Now we can express everything in terms of $v \in [0, 1)$,
$$F = \frac{(v^2+3)^3+6(v^2-1)^2}{2(v^2+3)^3}=\frac12+\frac3{v^2+3}\left(\frac4{v^2+3}-1\right)^2\le \frac12+\frac3{3}\left(\frac43-1\right)^2=\frac{11}{18}$$
clearly this is a higher maximum than the earlier case, and equality is possible when $(u, v) = (\frac12, 0) \iff x=y=\frac14$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $P$ be the given expression we want to maximise.

From the hypothesis, we get $xy+yz+zx=\dfrac{1}{4}(x+y+z)^2$

So, $P=\dfrac{x^3+y^3+z^3}{2(x+y+z)(xy+yz+zx)}=\dfrac{2(x^3+y^3+z^3)}{(x+y+z)^3}$

$\qquad \;\;=2\left[\left(\dfrac{x}{x+y+z}\right)^3+\left(\dfrac{y}{x+y+z}\right)^3+\left(\dfrac{z}{x+y+z}\right)^3\right]$

Let $a=\dfrac{x}{x+y+z}; b=\dfrac{y}{x+y+z}; c=\dfrac{z}{x+y+z}$, we have $\left\{\begin{array}{l}a+b+c=1\\ab+bc+ca=\dfrac{1}{4}\end{array}\right]$

Or $\left\{\begin{array}{l}b+c=1-a\\bc=a^2-a+\dfrac{1}{4}\end{array}\right]$

From the inequality $(b+c)^2\ge 4bc$, we get $0\le a\le\dfrac{2}{3}$.

We have:

$P=2(a^3+b^3+c^3)$

$\quad =2(a^3+(b+c)^3-3bc(b+c)$

$\quad =2\left[a^3+(1-a)^3-3\left(a^2-a+\dfrac{1}{4}\right)(1-a)\right]$

$\quad =6a^3-6a^2+\dfrac{3}{2}a+\dfrac{1}{2}$

$\quad =\dfrac{11}{18}+\dfrac{1}{18}(3a-2)(6a-1)^2\le\dfrac{11}{18}$

So, $\max P=\dfrac{11}{18}\approx {\boxed {0.611}}$.

The equality holds when $(x,y,z)=(4k,k,k)$ or any permutations.

Comment: This is a lot simpler than @Macavity's solution.

Answer (score 1):

Let $P$ be the expression we want to maximise.

Using the following notation: $S_1=x+y+z$, $S_2=xy+xz+yz$ and $S_3=xyz$.

From the hypothesis we get that, $S_1^2=4S2$.

So the expression we want to maximise is:

$P=\dfrac{x^3+y^3+z^3}{(x+y+z)(x^2+y^2+z^2)}=\dfrac{S_1^3-3S_1S_2+3S3}{2S_1S_2}$

Then, simplify it using the hypothesis, in a way such that we only get in terms of $S_1$ and $S_3$ :

$P=\dfrac{1}{2}+\dfrac{6S_3}{S_1^3}$

Now, consider a polynomial with roots $x,y,z$. Ofcourse it is $F(x)=x^3-S_1x^2+S_2x-S_3$. Then, for the roots to be real, the discriminant of this polynomial must be $\geq 0$, so:

$S_1^2S_2^2-4S_2^3-4S_1^3S_3+18S_1S_2S_3-27S_3^2 \geq 0$

Again, using the hypothesis, we get:

$\dfrac{1}{2}S_1^3-27S_3 \geq 0$

Hence, $\dfrac{S_3}{S_1^3} \leq \dfrac{1}{54}$

Finally, $P \leq \dfrac{1}{2}+6\left(\dfrac{1}{54}\right)=\boxed{\dfrac{11}{18}}$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

As we know:
$$x^3+y^3+z^3=(x+y+z)(x^2+y^2+z^2-xy-yz-zx)+3xyz$$
and $$x^2+y^2+z^2=2(xy+yz+zx)$$
So, 
$$x^3+y^3+z^3=\frac{1}{2}(x+y+z)(x^2+y^2+z^2)+3xyz$$
Substituting this in the expression gives:
$$\frac{\frac{1}{2}(x+y+z)(x^2+y^2+z^2)+3xyz}{(x+y+z)(x^2+y^2+z^2)}$$
$$=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{3xyz}{(x+y+z)(x^2+y^2+z^2)}$$
Now, substitute $x^2+y^2+z^2=2(xy+yz+zx)$ to get,
$$\frac{1}{2}+\frac{3}{2(x+y+z)(\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y}+\frac{1}{z})}$$
You should now be able to do this.

Comment: I think that doesn't find the value as a number.

Comment: @Nikunj From here I get the maximum value as $\frac{2}{3}$ which is an upper bound, but not the lowest upper bound.

Comment: @user330477 true that's why it's a hint and not a complete answer.

Comment: @user330477 They can be $0$ as well?

Comment: $x,y$ and $z$ ${{}}$

Comment: @Nikunj Then we will have the indeterminate form.

Comment: @user330477 how can you assume that the maximum value will be taken at $x=0$

Comment: I suppose it is a boundary for $x$ and by extreme-value theorem, max/min are achieved at extremities.

Comment: @user330477 How did you get that upper bound ($2/3$)?